# Create vg from different block size disks

Tags: lvm

Is there a rationale why Linux still supports creating vg from different block size disks by Changing `allow_mixed_block_sizes` to `1` in
`/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`.

As I know it will lead to data corruption if I create lv from pv has different block size.

What I mean what cases can I create vg from different block size disks without having data corruption or problems at file system?

Comment: Never heard of this option before, so it was added recently (2 year-ish).

[github commit 040453](https://github.com/lvmteam/lvm2/commit/0404539edb25e4a9d3456bb3e6b402aa2767af6b)

[lvm mailinglist discussion](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-lvm/253b63e7-e23b-9a0a-d677-a114c00a5134@linux.ibm.com/)

so I guess the option mainly exists for people who need the old behavior back to avoid breaking existing setups.

Answer (score 1):

> What i mean what cases can i create vg from different block size disks without having data corruption or problems at file system

The data corruption "problem" exists only if you create logical volue that uses the PVs with different sector sizes so if you make sure to not do that it's safe to have a VG with multiple different sector sizes. Both `lvcreate` and `lvresize` accept PV (list of PVs) as an optional argument so you can relatively easily make sure the LV will be allocated (and stay allocated after resize) on the given PV. So if you want you can create one LV on the 512 PV and second one on the 4096 sector size PV.

I would create two different VGs in this situation, but the option to have one VG and deal with the risk of data loss manually with every `lvcreate` and `lvresize` is there if someone wants it (but not allowing it is a very good default behaviour).

Comment: I know you can make lv use a specific pv but that leads us to another question, why would I add the unused pv in this vg?

Comment: It doesn't have to be unused, you can make one LV on the 512 PV and second on the 4096 PV. As I said, from my point of view it makes more sense to have two VGs in this case, but it is possible.